# Bind object (with list member) to datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, list, datagrid

I've got a problem. I want to bind an List of Objects to a datagrid. The binding is no problem, it's working but I've got a problem with one member of these objects: a List type.

The DataGrid only shows "(Collection)" in this cell. Here is my class:

```
public class ObjectOfMyProgram
{
    double val1;
    double val2;
    double result;

    List<double> input;
}
```

When I bind it to my dataGrid I get a column:

[Input]
(Collection)
(Collection)
(Collection)
(Collection)

Can anyone help me to show the double values correctly, each in one column?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this `ASP.NET`? Also, what *type* of column is it bound to? A text box column?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nice first post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bind a DataGrid to a collection it is necessary to specify which data each column should take from the bound object. You do it this way:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="val1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding val1}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <!-- add more columns here -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For simple types you can use these templates instead of `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

- `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` for boolean values
- `DataGridComboBoxColumn` for enumerable values
- `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` for Uri values
- `DataGridTextColumn` to show text values